# error appears in the appcompat version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
}
```

This cause error in my project

Error log:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0-alpha3, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha3 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1)
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
>   are incompatible, or can lead to bugs

Comment: Can you please post the Error?

Comment: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0-alpha3, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha3 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs.

Answer (score 4):

`Firebase-core:16.0.0` dependencies is implicitly depends on support library 26.1.0. So, you need to override it by adding the same library but with your specific version. For example:

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
   implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha3'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-alpha3'

   ...
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
}
```

Side note, don't use alpha version of library on your production code.

Answer (score 1):

In `Project>app>build.gradle`, find and Change it.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too for fixing this issue,
you should modify the build.gradle file (Module:app),
from:
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-**alpha3**'

to:
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-**alpha1**'

I hope this would fix your problem (worked for me).

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
```